# PHP- Laravel How to call function inside a function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have following code as below:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
  $this->isRequestInvalid($request);
  $result = $request->ssid;

  return $result;

}

public function isRequestInvalid($request)
{
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'ssid'  => 'required',
            'sid'   => 'required',
            'receiptinfo' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return "Something";
        }
        return true;
}
```

I think, if the function isRequestInvalid($request) is work. it should be return "Something"; But, why my code running even the function was called and return?

**Note: I don't want to added if condition inside __invoke()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuz you do not have anything that use or store the return value from `$this->isRequestInvalid($request);`
You may return false when validation fails

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return false;
}
```

and do the handling in `__invoke`

```
if (!$this->isRequestInvalid($request);) {
    return "Something";
}
```